# Laravel relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

This is my relation:

`App\Square\Topics\Topic::find(1)->subscriptions()->get();`

And I receive this back:

```
>>> App\Square\Topics\Topic::find(1)->subscriptions()->get();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#786
     all: [
       App\Square\Subscriptions\Subscription {#787
         id: 1,
         user_id: 1,
         subscription_id: 1,
         subscription_type: "App\Square\Topics\Topic",
         created_at: "2016-10-03 16:08:31",
         updated_at: "2016-10-03 16:08:31",
       },
     ],
   }
```

How would I get the user(s) of this relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the User of Subscriptions you may define this method in Subscription Model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

This will allow you to call user as an attribute of a subscription object.

So, then you can write a foreach to get each user of the related subscriptions, like this:

```
$subscriptions = App\Square\Topics\Topic::find(1)->subscriptions()->get();
foreach ($subscriptions as $subscription) {
    $u = $subscription->user;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thankyou very nice !

Comment: Good to know I was able to help you!!